# client failing to connect to ldap server

Tags: openldap

I am new to using ldap and slapd and I am having some trouble getting my client machine to connect to the server that is hosting slapd.
here is the run down:
on a ubuntu box I have an instance of virtualbox running a vm with CentOS.  I have installed and configured slapd on the CentOS vm and as long as I am on the vm I can use the ldapsearch, ldapadd, etc.  once I move to the client machine (the ubuntu distro housing the vm) I run the following:

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -b 'dc=example,dc=com' 'uid=Al' -d 255 -H ldap://192.168.1.73:389/
```

and the following is what I get

```
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://192.168.1.73:389/)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://192.168.1.73:389/??base)
ldap_pvt_sasl_getmech
ldap_search
put_filter: "(objectclass=*)"
put_filter: simple
put_simple_filter: "objectclass=*"
ldap_build_search_req ATTRS: supportedSASLMechanisms
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 192.168.1.73:389
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 192.168.1.73:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
ldap_close_socket: 3
ldap_msgfree
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

I can connect to the vm via ssh and run the ldapsearch, so connecting shouldn't be an issue.  I have configured the router to make the machines ip's static (both the vm and the physical)

any help I could get would be very appreciated.

Thanks,
Al

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firewall?  It wouldn't be inconceivable that out of the box the firewall would allow ssh through but not ldap.  You also need to verify that your ldap server is configured to listen on the outside interface and not just the loop back.  Openldap logging can also be setup to be very verbose about the connections it is receiving.  You should do that and monitor your syslog while attempting to connect.  That should give you enough information to figure out where the connection is being blocked.

Comment: I am using the following command to start slapd:
slapd -d 255 -f /etc/openldap/slpad.conf

in my reading I understood this to mean that slapd would listen to all traffic on port 389 for ldap:// and 686 for ldaps://, so the resulting ip is 0.0.0.0:389 nad the host ldap:///
as I mentioned though this is new to me so I could be misunderstanding what I'm reading.  
nmap shows ldap listening on port 389.

I will check the firewall setting and see what that shows.

thanks for you feedback

Comment: you were indeed correct the firewall was blocking the port.
Once I stopped the firewall all was well so not I just need to configure the firewall to allow for that port to have access

Again thank you for your assitance